# Sort and align 2 dataframes by values in corresponding columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that I want to sort that are similar in structure to what I have shown below, but the rows of values when looking at only the first 3 columns are jumbled. How do I sort the dataframes such that the row indices match?

Also it could so happen that there may not be matching rows in which case I want to create a blank entry in the other dataframe at that index. How would I go about doing this?

```
Dataframe1:
     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0       a    b    c    1
1       b    c    d    4
2       f    e    g    5

Dataframe2:
     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0       f    e    g    6
1       a    b    c    5
2       b    c    d    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,2],'b':[4,6,5]})
print(df.sort_values(df.columns.tolist()))
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  4
2  2  5
1  3  6
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I sort the dataframes such that the row indices match

You can sort by the columns that *should* determine order on both data frames & reset index.

```
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
df1.sort_values(cols).reset_index(drop=True)
#outputs:
  Col1 Col2 Col3  Col4
0    a    b    c     1
1    b    c    d     4
2    f    e    g     5

df2.sort_values(cols).reset_index(drop=True)
#outputs:
  Col1 Col2 Col3  Col4
0    a    b    c     5
1    b    c    d     3
2    f    e    g     6
```

> ...there may not be matching rows in which case I want to create a blank entry in the other dataframe at that index

lets add 1 more row to df1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'Col1': list('abfh'),
  'Col2': list('bceg'),
  'Col3': list('cdgi'),
  'Col4': [1,4,5,7]
})

df1
# outputs:
  Col1 Col2 Col3  Col4
0    a    b    c     1
1    b    c    d     4
2    f    e    g     5
3    h    g    i     7
```

We can use an *outer join* to add a blank row to `df2` where each column in pd.Nan at index `3`

*if you have sorted both databases already, you can merge using the indexes*

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, 'left', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_x', ''))
```

*otherwise, merge on the columns that *should* determine the sort order, this will create a new dataframe with joined values, sorted in the same way `df1` is sorted*

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, 'left', on=cols, suffixes=('_x', ''))
```

*Then filter out the columns from the left data frame*

```
df3.iloc[:, ~df3.columns.str.endswith('_x')]
#outputs:
  Col1 Col2 Col3  Col4
0    f    e    g   6.0
1    a    b    c   5.0
2    b    c    d   3.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```